# Call service method from spark

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-spark, spark-java

I'm using spark with spring boot. I have a service ( spring bean ), which I want to call for batch of data. The issue is that I keep getting `Task not serializable` exception.

```
javaRDD.foreachPartition(iterator -> {
            Iterators.partition(iterator, 200)
                    .forEachRemaining(value -> {
                        log.info("got value {}", value);
                        notificationService.post("topic", value);
                    });
        });
```

As far as I understood from different places, it's because we're calling method of service in cluster and for that purpose the service class needs to be Serializable to be transferred to executors which are going to run it.
The question is how I can get rid of this and is there any best practices to do it?

Comment: never seen this type of usage. What is the idea out of curiosity?

Comment: idea was to read from db via spark-sql, and send notifications by batches
I just didn't want to write a scheduler job to read db chunk by chunk, but wanted to try doing the same via spark

Comment: Spark is a processing engine not a db.